# Don't have any mouse-actions in CSS class

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website for a LHBT community in The Netherlands.

I am using a template that I can use for multiple websites and I want to offer a e-mail subscription button. The sub-box looks like this

[image]

```
.cta .cta-inner {
  position: relative;
  padding: 3rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
}

.cta .cta-inner:before {
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.5rem;
  bottom: -0.5rem;
  left: -0.5rem;
  right: -0.5rem;
  border: 0.25rem solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
}
```

When I want to use some mouse-actions (like using the form / button) it does not give any response. Also I don't see the vertical-bar-cursor that tells me that I can select the text. But when I remove the second line of `.cta .cta-inner:before` - it works again.

But when I do that, I don't have the cute border around the box.

[image: second]

This is my HTML

```
<section class="page-section cta closeBorder">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-9 mx-auto">
          <div class="cta-inner rounded">
            <h2 class="section-heading mb-4">
              <span class="text-center section-heading-upper">Wordt lid van de nieuwsbrief</span>
              <span class="text-center section-heading-lower">Blijf op de hoogte</span>
            </h2>
            <p class="mb-0 text-center">When you walk into our shop to start your day, we are dedicated to providing you with friendly service, a welcoming atmosphere, and above all else, excellent products made with the highest quality ingredients. If you are not satisfied, please let us know and we will do whatever we can to make things right!</p>
            <b class="pull-left"><em>E-mailadres:</em></b>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email">
            <input type="submit" class="btn-block subBtn" value="Abonneer!">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

How can I get the style of the first picture with the ability to use the form?

Added snippet

```css
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Business Casual v5.0.3 (https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/business-casual)
 * Copyright 2013-2019 Start Bootstrap
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-business-casual/blob/master/LICENSE)/
 */

@font-face {
  font-family: Bahnschrift;
  src: url(BAHNSCHRIFT.TTF);
}

body {
  font-family: 'Bahnschrift' !important;
  /* background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(47, 23, 15, 0.65))), url("../img/bg.jpg"); */
  /* background: linear-gradient(rgba(47, 23, 15, 0.65)), url("../img/bg.jpg"); */
  background-color: #ec008c; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, #ec008c, #fc6767); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  /* font-family: 'Raleway'; */
}

p {
  line-height: 1.75;
}

.text-faded {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.site-heading {
  margin-top: 5rem;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1;
  /* font-family: 'Raleway'; */
}

.site-heading .site-heading-upper {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.site-heading .site-heading-lower {
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 4rem;
}

.page-section {
  margin-top: 5rem;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

.section-heading {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.section-heading .section-heading-upper {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.section-heading .section-heading-lower {
  display: block;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.bg-faded {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
}

#mainNav {
  background-color: #002060;
  /* font-family: 'Raleway'; */
}

#mainNav .navbar-brand {
  color: #e6a756;
}

#mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-weight: 800;
}

#mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link {
  color: #fc6767;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link:hover {
    color: #e6a756;
  }
}

.btn-xl {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.intro {
  position: relative;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .intro .intro-img {
    width: 75%;
    float: right;
  }
  .intro .intro-text {
    left: 0;
    width: 60%;
    margin-top: 3rem;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .intro .intro-text .intro-button {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .intro .intro-text {
    width: 45%;
  }
}

.cta {
  padding-top: 5rem;
  padding-bottom: 5rem;
  background-color: #002060;
}

.cta .cta-inner {
  position: relative;
  padding: 3rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
}

.cta .cta-inner:before {
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.5rem;
  bottom: -0.5rem;
  left: -0.5rem;
  right: -0.5rem;
  border: 0.25rem solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .about-heading .about-heading-img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  .about-heading .about-heading-content {
    margin-top: -5rem;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .product-item .product-item-title {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-bottom: -3rem;
  }
  .product-item .product-item-img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    max-width: 60vw;
  }
  .product-item .product-item-description {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: -3rem;
    max-width: 50vw;
  }
}

.list-hours {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.list-hours .list-hours-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(230, 167, 86, 0.5);
  padding-bottom: .25rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-style: italic;
}

.list-hours .list-hours-item.today {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #e6a756;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .list-hours {
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
  }
}

.address strong {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.footer {
  background-color: rgba(47, 23, 15, 0.9);
}

.text-primary {
  color: #e6a756 !important;
}

.bg-primary {
  background-color: #e6a756 !important;
}

.btn {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(33, 37, 41, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(33, 37, 41, 0.1);
}

.btn-primary {
  background-color: #ec008c; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bo left, #ec008c, #fc6767); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
  border: 0;
}

.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:active {
  background-color: #df902a;
  border-color: #df902a;
}

.font-weight-light {
  font-weight: 100 !important;
}

.logo {
 width: 10%;
}

.pull-left {
 font-size: 13pt;
}

.subBtn {
 background-color: #ec008c;
 border: 0;
 border: 1px solid #ec008c;
 border-radius: 7px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<section class="page-section cta closeBorder">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-9 mx-auto">
          <div class="cta-inner rounded">
            <h2 class="section-heading mb-4">
              <span class="text-center section-heading-upper">Wordt lid van de nieuwsbrief</span>
              <span class="text-center section-heading-lower">Blijf op de hoogte</span>
            </h2>
            <p class="mb-0 text-center">When you walk into our shop to start your day, we are dedicated to providing you with friendly service, a welcoming atmosphere, and above all else, excellent products made with the highest quality ingredients. If you are not satisfied, please let us know and we will do whatever we can to make things right!</p>
   <b class="pull-left"><em>E-mailadres:</em></b>
   <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email">
   <input type="submit" class="btn-block subBtn" value="Abonneer!">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: do you have to have the `:before`? You could just add the border to the `.cta-inner`? Then you wont have any issues with the before overlapping your form.

Comment: @coops I just shared the whole code in a snippet in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `z-index:-1` to `.cta .cta-inner:before`

Also I added `z-index:2` to `.cta .cta-inner`

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Bahnschrift;
  src: url(BAHNSCHRIFT.TTF);
}

body {
  font-family: 'Bahnschrift' !important;
  /* background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(47, 23, 15, 0.65))), url("../img/bg.jpg"); */
  /* background: linear-gradient(rgba(47, 23, 15, 0.65)), url("../img/bg.jpg"); */
  background-color: #ec008c; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, #ec008c, #fc6767); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  /* font-family: 'Raleway'; */
}

p {
  line-height: 1.75;
}

.text-faded {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.site-heading {
  margin-top: 5rem;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  line-height: 1;
  /* font-family: 'Raleway'; */
}

.site-heading .site-heading-upper {
  display: block;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.site-heading .site-heading-lower {
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 4rem;
}

.page-section {
  margin-top: 5rem;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

.section-heading {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.section-heading .section-heading-upper {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.section-heading .section-heading-lower {
  display: block;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.bg-faded {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
}

#mainNav {
  background-color: #002060;
  /* font-family: 'Raleway'; */
}

#mainNav .navbar-brand {
  color: #e6a756;
}

#mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-weight: 800;
}

#mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link {
  color: #fc6767;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  #mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  }
  #mainNav .navbar-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link:hover {
    color: #e6a756;
  }
}

.btn-xl {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.intro {
  position: relative;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .intro .intro-img {
    width: 75%;
    float: right;
  }
  .intro .intro-text {
    left: 0;
    width: 60%;
    margin-top: 3rem;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .intro .intro-text .intro-button {
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -2rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .intro .intro-text {
    width: 45%;
  }
}

.cta {
  padding-top: 5rem;
  padding-bottom: 5rem;
  background-color: #002060;
}

.cta .cta-inner {
  position: relative;
  padding: 3rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
  z-index:2;
}

.cta .cta-inner:before {
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  content: '';
  z-index:-1;
  position: absolute;
  top: -0.5rem;
  bottom: -0.5rem;
  left: -0.5rem;
  right: -0.5rem;
  border: 0.25rem solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .about-heading .about-heading-img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  .about-heading .about-heading-content {
    margin-top: -5rem;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .product-item .product-item-title {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-bottom: -3rem;
  }
  .product-item .product-item-img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    max-width: 60vw;
  }
  .product-item .product-item-description {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-top: -3rem;
    max-width: 50vw;
  }
}

.list-hours {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.list-hours .list-hours-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(230, 167, 86, 0.5);
  padding-bottom: .25rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-style: italic;
}

.list-hours .list-hours-item.today {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #e6a756;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .list-hours {
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
  }
}

.address strong {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.footer {
  background-color: rgba(47, 23, 15, 0.9);
}

.text-primary {
  color: #e6a756 !important;
}

.bg-primary {
  background-color: #e6a756 !important;
}

.btn {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(33, 37, 41, 0.1);
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px 0px rgba(33, 37, 41, 0.1);
}

.btn-primary {
  background-color: #ec008c; /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bo left, #ec008c, #fc6767); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
  border: 0;
}

.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:active {
  background-color: #df902a;
  border-color: #df902a;
}

.font-weight-light {
  font-weight: 100 !important;
}

.logo {
 width: 10%;
}

.pull-left {
 font-size: 13pt;
}

.subBtn {
 background-color: #ec008c;
 border: 0;
 border: 1px solid #ec008c;
 border-radius: 7px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<section class="page-section cta closeBorder">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xl-9 mx-auto">
          <div class="cta-inner rounded">
            <h2 class="section-heading mb-4">
              <span class="text-center section-heading-upper">Wordt lid van de nieuwsbrief</span>
              <span class="text-center section-heading-lower">Blijf op de hoogte</span>
            </h2>
            <p class="mb-0 text-center">When you walk into our shop to start your day, we are dedicated to providing you with friendly service, a welcoming atmosphere, and above all else, excellent products made with the highest quality ingredients. If you are not satisfied, please let us know and we will do whatever we can to make things right!</p>
            <b class="pull-left"><em>E-mailadres:</em></b>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email">
            <input type="submit" class="btn-block subBtn" value="Abonneer!">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: That also removes the first border, as in the second picture.

Comment: please add your all code. because I can't see any border in your example.

Comment: I just shared the whole code in a snippet in the question.